# Range queries on a binary string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, data-structures, modulus

**Binary-Decimal**

We are given a **binary string** S of **length n**, in which each character is either **'1' or '0'**.

And we are asked to perform several queries on the string.

In each query we are given  integers **L** and **R**.
And we have to tell the value of sub-string **S[l..r]**, in **decimal representation**.

**Sample testcase:**

```
Input:

1011 (string S)
5    (number of queries)
1 1  (l, r)
2 2
1 2
2 4
1 4

Output:
1      (1 * 2^0 == 1)
0
2
3      (0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0)
11     (1 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0 = 11)
```

**Constraints**

```
1 < N < 10^5
1 < Q < 10^5
```

As the number can be very large, we are required to print it modulo **10^9 + 7.**

**Approach**

So basically we need to convert binary representation sub-string S[l..r] in it's decimal.

I **pre-computed** the results of **S[i...n-1]** for all **i:[0, n-1]** in **array B**.
So now **B[i]** represents the decimal number representation of sub-string **S[i..n-1]**.

```
vector<int> pow(1e5, 1);
for(int i = 1; i < 1e5; i++) {
    pow[i] = (pow[i - 1] * 2) % mod;
}

string s;
getline(cin, s);
vector<int> B(n, 0);
int prev = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    B[(n - 1) - i] = (prev + (s[(n - 1) - i] == '1' ? pow[i] : 0)) % mod;
    prev = B[(n - 1) - i];
}

while(q--) {
    int l, r;
    cin >> l >> r;
    cout << ((B[l] - (r + 1 < n ? B[r + 1] : 0) + mod) % mod) / pow[n - (r + 1)]<< "\n";
}

return 0;
```

With the above **approach** only **sample testcase** got passed and all other cases are giving the **wrong answers(WA)**.

I even tried using **Segment tree** for this problem but that is also not working.

> What is the correct approach to solve this problem ?

Comment: You fill B[] from the right, but use s[] from the left?

Comment: @MBo, yeah that was a typo, fixed it, but still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `V[k]` to be the value of the digits of `S` starting with the `k`th one.

Then the value of the substring `S[l..r] = (V[l] - V[r+1]) / 2^(n - r - 1)`.  (Something like that, I may have an off by one error.  Play with small examples.)

Now the useful fact about `10^9 + 7` is that it is a prime.  (The first 10 digit prime.) Which means that dividing by 2 is the same as multiplying by `2^(10^9 + 5)`.  Which is a constant that you can figure out with repeated squaring.  And raising that constant to a high power can be done very efficiently using repeated squaring.

With this you can create a lookup table for `V`, and then do your queries in time `O(log(n))`.

Comment: For those who want a more concrete reason behind `2^(10^9 + 5)` being the multiplicative inverse of `2` modulo `10^9 + 7`: 

For any prime `p`, the multiplicative group `{1, ..., p-1}` of the prime field `Z/pZ` (i.e. the field `{0, ..., p-1}` of integers formed by addition and multiplication `mod p`) is cyclic, i.e. `x^(p-1) = 1 mod p` for all `1 <= x <= p - 1`. Multiplying both sides by `x^(-1)`, `x^(-1) = x^(p-2) mod p`.  This stands true for all primes `p` and all `1 <= x <= p-1`.

In this case, `2^(-1) = 2^(10^9 + 7 - 2) mod (10^9 + 7)`.

Comment: @EvilTak , so basically the formula we are using is correct, but the way modulo(%) work in this formula with division operation is producing the wrong answer. I don't know how modulo works in division and multiplicative inverse.
Can you provide me any source from which I can learn modulo multiplicative inverse from basics.

Comment: @tusharRawat instead of dividing by `2^(n - r - 1)`, multiply by its modular inverse `(2^(10^9 + 5)) ^ (n - r - 1)`. Note that `2^(10^9 + 5) = 500000004 mod (10^9 + 7)`, so `S[l..r] = (V[l] - V[r+1]) * 500000004^(n - r - 1) mod (10^9 + 7)`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems the same as regular sum range-queries, except (1) we need to store the partial sums mod 10^9 + 7, (2) during retrieval, we need to "shift" the relevant sections of the full sum by the length of the sections on their right. To "shift" in this case would mean multiplying by 2^(length_of_suffix) mod 10^9 + 7. And of course sum the sections mod 10^9 + 7.

But btilly's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559586/2034787) seems much simpler :)